# C# File.ReadAllLines only recognizing the first line

Tags: c#

I am trying to using File.ReadAllLines to obtain an array containing every line. My text file contains one word per line so every index of the array should contain one word, although when I run the code it only prints out the first line.

```
foreach (string emotion in emotions)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Griffin\\Documents\\C#\\thavma\\thavma\\bin\\Debug\\libraries\\" + emotion + ".lib");
            emotiondict.Add(emotion, lines);
            foreach (string f in lines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(f);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

For reference here is string[] emotions:

```
string[] emotions = new string[]
        { "anger","anticipation","disgust", "fear", "joy", "negative", "positive", "sadness", "surprise", "trust"};
```

As well as a sample of part of the file I am trying to read:

```
abandoned
abandonment
abhor
abhorrent
abolish
abomination
abuse
accursed
accusation
accused
accuser
...
```

When I run the code all that prints is the word "abandoned", and I am not sure exactly what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: you can check by removing  Console.ReadLine();

Comment: Have you debugged and checked the value of lines after `File.ReadAllLines`? With `Console.ReadLine()` you're code is waiting for an input before it continues. That's your problem...

Comment: There's a `Console.ReadLine()`, so you'll have to press Enter after every line. Use your debugger to pause your program if you want to know what it's doing.

Comment: Move `Console.ReadLine();` *out* of the loop: `foreach (string f in lines) {Console.WriteLine(f);}  Console.ReadLine();`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

In your Loop. This "stops" the software and awaits user input, for example you can use this to get what the user typed. Long Story short: if you run your program und press repeatedly Enter it would work. I suggest changing it to

```
foreach (string f in lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(f);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

This should work fine

Answer (score 0):

The `Console.ReadLine();` code will used input stream. Therefore, The program will wait till the user input something. Read Below article.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Console_ReadLine

Try this code.  and also make sure `lines` has values.

```
        foreach (string emotion in emotions)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Griffin\\Documents\\C#\\thavma\\thavma\\bin\\Debug\\libraries\\" + emotion + ".lib");
            emotiondict.Add(emotion, lines);
            foreach (string f in lines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(f);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.